# Evaluating an integral using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm having trouble evaluating the complex integral
\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{|z-\alpha|^2|z-\beta|^2z}dz,
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ refers to the unit circle, the integral being taken anticlockwise, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants with $|\alpha|<1$ and $|\beta|<1$. The integrand has singularities at $\alpha$, $\beta$, and 0. I've already computed the residual of the integrand $f$ at 0, and got $Res(f,0) = \frac{1}{|\alpha|^2|\beta|^2}$. I can't figure out the residuals at $\alpha$ and $\beta$. They don't seem to be simple poles, since the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{z->\alpha}\frac{z-\alpha}{|z-\alpha|^2|z-\beta|^2z} = 
\lim_{z->\alpha}\frac{1}{(\overline{z}-\overline{\alpha})|z-\beta|^2z}
\end{equation}
does not exist.

Comment: The integrand is not analytic or meromorphic.

Comment: Isn't it analytic at every point except for 0,$\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: The function $z\mapsto |z|^2$ is not analytic--in fact, it is holomorphic only at $z=0$, and nowhere else.

Comment: Use $z \bar{z} = 1$ and convert the integrand to a meromorphic function.